# Generate .jpg instead of .png using phpqrcode library

Tags: php, qr-code

How should I generate the qrcode image as .jpg instead of .png?
I tried `QRcode::jpg($qrcode, $file, 'L', 10, 3);`  but it is not working, giving this error: **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method QRcode::jpg()**. PNG works fine as it is `QRcode::png($qrcode, $file, 'L', 10, 3);`.

Note: this is the phpqrcode library: http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

Comment: http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/docs/html/class_q_rcode.html - this documentation page shows you what functions exist in the QRCode class. It does not have the capability to output to jpg. That library seems to be quite old now...maybe you can find something newer which has more features.

Comment: Either that or you can output to PNG and then use another tool to convert to jpg, although that's a bit inefficient. Do you really need jpg specifically?

Comment: Yes, because I need to use PHP to generate qr code image and implement it into another desktop program, which somehow only can load jpg files. it is a very old program (delphi based language)